# ZMQ Pub requires while loop to send message

Tags: python, message-queue, zeromq

I've noticed weird behavior with `zmq.PUB`, it requires to have while loop to send message. Example:

Imagine I have a sub waiting for a pub:

```
context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
subscriber.connect ('tcp://*:5555')
while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
```

And I want to send a message from pub:

```
context = zmq.Context()
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind('tcp://*:%5555')
publisher.send(''.join(sys.argv[1]))
```

This message won't reach the sub for some reason. You can fix this by adding `while` or `for` loop before  sending a message `publisher.send(''.join(sys.argv[1]))`

Why is that? Do I always have to have a loop with publisher to distribute messages to multiple workers?

Comment: Is your call to `publisher.send` the last line in the script (that is, does the script exit immediately after that)?

Comment: @larsks yes, but still, is it suppose to send message on `.send`? If it's not then it looks to me as wrong design, since I'm using blocking `zmq` module not the one with `gevent`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are a few problems here.

First, the code you've posted has a number of errors in it (for example, you can't `connect` to `tcp://*:5555`), but I'll assume that it's representative of what you're trying to do.

**Update**

I'm going to leave my original answer below, because I think it's
still useful although not directly relevant to your question (possibly
due to a morning caffeine deficit, who knows?).

Since your publisher is calling `send` with a single message and then
exiting immediately, the subscribers probably never have time to
`connect()`.  You would typically expect the code calling `bind` to be
the long-running process.  If you insert a `sleep` between the `bind`
and `send` call, things will work as expected:

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.bind('tcp://*:5555')

time.sleep(1)
pub.send('message 1')
```

This works fine, assuming the following subscriber:

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sub.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

while True:
    msg = sub.recv()
    print msg
```

However, this isn't a great solution...anything using `sleep` for
synchronization is bound to fail.  A different way of solving this
would be to have your publisher open both a `PUB` socket and a `REP`
socket.  To send a message to all subscribers, your tool would open a
`REQ` socket to the broker, which would then publish it to all
subscribers.

---

Original answer follows

---

The problem you're hitting is probably
[this](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/94).  Since you are
having your *subscriber* call `bind` and your sender call `connect`,
it is likely that your are simply losing the message because there is
a delay between a successful connection and the subscriber
successfully subscribing to messages.  Also see the question "Why do I see
different behavior when I bind a socket versus connect a socket?" in
[the FAQ](http://zeromq.org/area:faq#toc6).

Demonstrating this with code, if we have this subscriber:

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sub.bind('tcp://*:5555')

while True:
    msg = sub.recv()
    print msg
```

And the following publisher:

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

pub.send('message 1')
pub.send('message 2')
time.sleep(1)
pub.send('message 3')
```

The subscriber will probably always end up printing:

```
message 3
```

This is because the first to `send` operations happen to quickly.

This is generally not considered a problem, since pub/sub is explicitly not a reliable transport mechanism.  In the typical use case, there is a single publisher calling `bind` and multiple subscribers calling `connect` that may not all be present initially or continuously.  There is no guarantee that every subscriber will receive every message.

If you need to reliably transport a single message, consider a `REQ`/`REP` socket pair instead.

Comment: Actually, In my code I use `connect` on `SUB` and `bind` on `PUB`. And I also need to distribute my message across multiple subs

Comment: That wasn't the example you posted, which makes it hard to come up with an accurate answer.  I'll take a another look.

Comment: Erhm.. It was from the begging, look at the difference in your example. And I have to agree about waiting for the socket to send message with `sleep`, but in really it does not really send the message; if, however, you use any kind of loop it will send message

Comment: Was it? I must not have had enough coffee, then.